# Capturing a screenshot across multiple displays

Tags: c#, winforms

As part of my application I'd like to be able to grap a screenshot of a chosen area on my desktop. I came across example code of how to do this a while ago (if I could remember where I would cite) and the example works nicely, however it has a problem with multiple displays.

It works by creating a transparent full screen form and then you draw a rubberband in it to designate the area. The issue is it spawns on the main display, and only allows you to grab content on that display or one to the right of it. If you have 3 displays and your master is the center there is no way to grab the left.

My question is how I can allow capture across all 3 displays.

Example code:

**RubberBand.cs**

```
public partial class RubberBand : Form
{
    public Point lastLoc;
    public Size lastSize;

    bool mouseDown = false;
    Point mouseDownPoint = Point.Empty;
    Point mousePoint = Point.Empty;
    Main mainform;
    Pen pen;
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();

    public RubberBand(Main mainform)
    {
        this.mainform = mainform;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.Opacity = .30;
        this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        pen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed, 3);
        pen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot;

        int maxX = 0;
        int maxY = 0;

        foreach (Screen screen in System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens)
        {
            int x = screen.Bounds.X + screen.Bounds.Width;
            if (x > maxX)
                maxX = x;
            int y = screen.Bounds.Y + screen.Bounds.Height;
            if (y > maxY)
                maxY = y;

        }
        bounds.X = 0;
        bounds.Y = 0;
        bounds.Width = maxX;
        bounds.Height = maxY;

        this.Size = new Size(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

    }



    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        mouseDown = true;
        mousePoint = mouseDownPoint = e.Location;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        mouseDown = false;

        // corey
        this.lastLoc = new Point(Math.Min(mouseDownPoint.X, mousePoint.X), Math.Min(mouseDownPoint.Y, mousePoint.Y));
        this.lastSize = new Size(Math.Abs(mouseDownPoint.X - mousePoint.X), Math.Abs(mouseDownPoint.Y - mousePoint.Y));
        this.Close();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        mousePoint = e.Location;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnPaint(e);

        Region region = new Region(bounds);

        if (mouseDown)
        {

            Rectangle selectionWindow = new Rectangle(
                Math.Min(mouseDownPoint.X, mousePoint.X),
                Math.Min(mouseDownPoint.Y, mousePoint.Y),
                Math.Abs(mouseDownPoint.X - mousePoint.X),
                Math.Abs(mouseDownPoint.Y - mousePoint.Y));

            // make a hole, where we can see thru this form
            region.Xor(selectionWindow);

            e.Graphics.FillRegion(Brushes.Black, region);

        }
        else
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRegion(Brushes.LightGray, region);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen,
                mousePoint.X, 0,
                mousePoint.X, this.Size.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen,
                0, mousePoint.Y,
                this.Size.Width, mousePoint.Y);

        }
    }
}
```

**RubberBand.Designer.cs**

```
partial class RubberBand
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        //
        // RubberBand
        //
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
        this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Cross;
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Name = "RubberBand";
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.Text = "RubberBand";
        this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

}
```

**And this is the code that calls it:**

```
    private void ShowRubberBand()
    {
        using (RubberBand rbf = new RubberBand(this))
        {

            rbf.ShowDialog();

            Size sLastSize = rbf.lastSize;

            if (sLastSize.Width > 0 && sLastSize.Height > 0)
            {
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
                r.Location = rbf.lastLoc;
                r.Size = sLastSize;
                CaptureBitmap(r);
            }
        }

        this.Show();
    }

    private void CaptureBitmap(Rectangle r)
    {
        bitmap = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(r.Location, new Point(0, 0), r.Size);
        }

        PasteImage(bitmap);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`this.Location = new Point(0, 0);` is related to the main screen top left corner. Screens on the left or above the main(primary) screen have negative location coordinates. You have to take it into account when position your window and set its size.

In RubberBand constructor:

```
    int maxX = 0;
    int maxY = 0;
    int minX = 0;
    int minY = 0;

    foreach (Screen screen in System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens)
    {
        int x = screen.Bounds.X + screen.Bounds.Width;
        if (x > maxX)
            maxX = x;
        int y = screen.Bounds.Y + screen.Bounds.Height;
        if (y > maxY)
            maxY = y;
        if(screen.Bound.X < minX) minX = screen.Bound.X;
        if(screen.Bound.Y < minY) minY = screen.Bound.Y;
    }

    bounds.X = minX;
    bounds.Y = minY;
    bounds.Width = maxX - minX;
    bounds.Height = maxY - minY;

    this.Location = new Point(bounds.X, bounds.Y);
    this.Size = new Size(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
```